# Java Tooltip : it shouldn't stay on the screen when the mouse cursor leaves a row from a javafx tableview

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip

I am lost. In fact, there is a javafx tableview which contains a few rows. There is only one column. The Tooltip class is used in order to show the row text content into a bubble. The bubble is shown when the mouse cursor is over the row and it has to disappear when the mouse cursor leaves the row.
The problem is that, sometimes, the bubble doesn't disappear. It stays on the screen and it doesn't move anymore. However, the application can be moved and used. The bubble doesn't move and seems to be sticked to the computer background.
Do you have an idea of how i could solve this problem ?

The code below is used in order to create and close the bubble:

```
    public void bindTooltip(final Node node, final Tooltip tooltip) {
    node.setOnMouseMoved(event -> tooltip.show(node, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY() + 15));
    node.setOnMouseExited((event) -> hideTooltip(tooltip));
}

private void hideTooltip(Tooltip tooltip) {
    if (tooltip.isShowing()) {
        tooltip.hide();
    }
}
```

The method bindTooltip is used in order to bind the row to the tooltip.

Thank you for your help.

Cordially,

Vinz

Comment: Can you provide a picture ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Looking at [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/DisplayfirstandlastnamewithtooltipusingaliasforListView.htm) example, `ListView` has a `setToolTip` method. I am guessing `TableView` has this also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `table.setRowFactory` to set the `ToolTip`. Example below. Code from [here](https://o7planning.org/en/11079/javafx-tableview-tutorial).

> Key code!

```
table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<UserAccount> row = new TableRow();
    Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
    row.setOnMouseEntered((event) -> {
        if (!row.isEmpty()) {
            UserAccount tempUserAccount = row.getItem();
            tooltip.setText(tempUserAccount.getLastName() + ", " + tempUserAccount.getFirstName());
            row.setTooltip(tooltip);
        }
    });

    return row;
});
```

> Full code

**Main**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewDemo2 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {

        TableView<UserAccount> table = new TableView<UserAccount>();

        // Create column UserName (Data type of String).
        TableColumn<UserAccount, String> userNameCol //
                = new TableColumn<UserAccount, String>("User Name");

        // Create column Email (Data type of String).
        TableColumn<UserAccount, String> emailCol//
                = new TableColumn<UserAccount, String>("Email");

        // Create column FullName (Data type of String).
        TableColumn<UserAccount, String> fullNameCol//
                = new TableColumn<UserAccount, String>("Full Name");

        // Create 2 sub column for FullName.
        TableColumn<UserAccount, String> firstNameCol//
                = new TableColumn<UserAccount, String>("First Name");

        TableColumn<UserAccount, String> lastNameCol //
                = new TableColumn<UserAccount, String>("Last Name");

        // Add sub columns to the FullName
        fullNameCol.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);

        // Active Column
        TableColumn<UserAccount, Boolean> activeCol//
                = new TableColumn<UserAccount, Boolean>("Active");

        // Defines how to fill data for each cell.
        // Get value from property of UserAccount. .
        userNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("userName"));
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
        activeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("active"));

        // Set Sort type for userName column
        userNameCol.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING);
        lastNameCol.setSortable(false);

        // Display row data
        ObservableList<UserAccount> list = getUserList();
        table.setItems(list);

        table.getColumns().addAll(userNameCol, emailCol, fullNameCol, activeCol);

        table.setRowFactory(tv -> {

            TableRow<UserAccount> row = new TableRow();
            Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
            row.setOnMouseEntered((event) -> {
                if (!row.isEmpty()) {
                    UserAccount tempUserAccount = row.getItem();
                    tooltip.setText(tempUserAccount.getLastName() + ", " + tempUserAccount.getFirstName());
                    row.setTooltip(tooltip);
                }
            });

            return row;
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.getChildren().add(table);

        stage.setTitle("TableView (o7planning.org)");

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private ObservableList<UserAccount> getUserList()
    {

        UserAccount user1 = new UserAccount(1L, "smith", "smith@gmail.com", //
                "Susan", "Smith", true);
        UserAccount user2 = new UserAccount(2L, "mcneil", "mcneil@gmail.com", //
                "Anne", "McNeil", true);
        UserAccount user3 = new UserAccount(3L, "white", "white@gmail.com", //
                "Kenvin", "White", false);

        ObservableList<UserAccount> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(user1, user2, user3);
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**UserAccount**

```
public class UserAccount
{

    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private boolean active;

    public UserAccount(Long id, String userName, String email, //
            String firstName, String lastName, boolean active)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public boolean isActive()
    {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active)
    {
        this.active = active;
    }

}
```